# Styles in FlatList

Tags: react-native

I am trying to display an image of the building along with the address, phone number and few links in my FlatList. If I put the line in my flatList:

```
   <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
```

then it displays the image along with all the address rows in one line and I cannot see the Phone Number and other data on the flatList. If I put them in separate rows then I get the image and all the data including address, phone number underneath the image. I want to put the image on the left like it is displaying right now and then the address, phone number and Online and direction link on the right side of it

Below is my code with stylesheet and the image:

```
_renderItem = ({item, index}) => {

 return(

   <View style={{ backgroundColor: index %2 ===0? '#FFD5C2':'#CC8B8C'}} >
                   <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <Image source={require('../images/test.png')} style = {styles.imageView}/>
                <Text  style={styles.Address1}>{item.addr} </Text>

                <View style={styles.phoneImg}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => { this.handleClick(`tel:${item.phone}`)}}
            >
                <Image source={require('../images/call.png')} style={styles.actionImage}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style={styles.Address1}>{item.phone}</Text>
              </View>

                <View style={styles.AddressRow}>
                {
                        item.Online != ''? <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => Linking.openURL(  item.Online )}>
                         <Image source={require('../images/www-icon.png')} style={styles.actionImage1}/>
                         </TouchableOpacity>: null 

                          }


              <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => Linking.openURL(item.Online)}>
                    <Text style={styles.underLineText}>Online</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>



                <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => Linking.openURL(destUrl)}>
                    <Text style={styles.underLineText}>Directions</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>


                <Text style={styles.AddressSpace} >Miles:{dist}</Text>



               </View>


            </View>
            </View>


        );

  }
```

Below is the image of the phone with the building

[image]

below is the image on the phone without the building

[image]

I just want to display the Building and address phone number on the right side of it on separate lines. I don't want it to be displayed beneath the building photo. Below is my stylesheet:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

MainContainer :{

// Setting up View inside content in Vertically center.
justifyContent: 'center',
flex:1,
margin: 10

},

item: {
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    height: 44,
  },
  container2:
    {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        paddingHorizontal: 15
    },
    underLineText: {
      fontSize: 17,
      textDecorationLine: 'underline',
      color: 'black',

      alignSelf: 'center',
      marginLeft: 20,
      paddingTop:10

    },

    underLineTextOnline: {
      fontSize: 17,
      textDecorationLine: 'underline',
      color: 'black',

      alignSelf: 'center',
      marginLeft: 20,
      paddingTop:5

    },

    title:{
      justifyContent: 'center',
      paddingTop: 10,
      alignItems: 'center',
      alignSelf: 'center',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      fontSize: 22,
      color: 'black',

      },

      Address1:{
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginRight: 20,
        fontSize: 17,

        color: 'black'
    },
    SerContent:{
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      fontSize: 16,
      paddingTop: 10,
      alignSelf: 'center',
      color: 'black',
      paddingBottom: 10
  },
  Address1:{
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginRight: 20,
    fontSize: 15,
    flexDirection:'column',
    color: 'black',
    marginLeft:10,
    textAlignVertical:'center'
},

AddressRow:{
  alignSelf: 'center',
  marginRight: 20,
  fontSize: 15,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  color: 'black'
},

phoneImg:{

  flexDirection: 'row',
  alignSelf: 'center',
  textAlignVertical:'center'
},
AddressSpace:{
  alignSelf: 'center',
  marginLeft: 20,
  fontSize: 15,
  marginLeft: 20,
  paddingTop:5,
  color: 'black'

},

actionImage:{
  flex:0,
  height:40,
  width:40,
  backgroundColor:'transparent',
  justifyContent:'center',
  alignItems:'center',
  marginTop:10,
  alignSelf:'center',
  flexDirection:'column',
  textAlignVertical:'center'
},

sepBoxes:{
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'column'

},
box: {
  height: 55,
  width:400,


},
box1: {
  backgroundColor: 'white'
},

actionImage1:{
  flex:0,
  height:40,
  width:50,
  backgroundColor:'transparent',
  justifyContent:'center',
  alignItems:'center',

  alignSelf:'center',
  flexDirection:'column'
},

imageView:{
width:'30%',
height:100,
margin:7,
borderRadius: 7

}


});
```

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Here is a demo doing what you want: https://snack.expo.io/@robertpurcea21/authentic-toffee Basically, you have a container with flex-direction row divided into 2 parts: - the image - a view that encapsulates all the small images and text If you have any uncertainties, or this is not what you intended to do, please comment below

Comment: Hi Robert, It worked!!, Please put this as an answer and I will accept it. Thank you again for all your help. This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution is to use flexbox and create one view that encapsulates all the texts and small images you want on the right side. That view will stay aside the image, occupying all the space left by it (by setting flex: 1), and both of them are going to stay in a view with flex-direction row (so you have your image on the left side and all the other content on the right)

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center", backgroundColor: "red"}}>
         <Image source={{uri: "https://via.placeholder.com/80x140"}} style={{width: 50, height: 150}} />

         <View style={{ backgroundColor: "green", flex: 1, alignItems: "center"}}>
            <Text>Building address</Text>

            <Image source={{ uri: "https://via.placeholder.com/40x50"}} style={{width: 50, height: 50}} />
            <Text>Online</Text>

            <Image source={{ uri: "https://via.placeholder.com/40x50"}} style={{width: 50, height: 50}} />
            <Image source={{ uri: "https://via.placeholder.com/40x50"}} style={{width: 50, height: 50}} />

            <Text>Directions</Text>
            <Text>Miles</Text>
         </View>

       </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[Here](https://snack.expo.io/@robertpurcea21/authentic-toffee-dont-delete---so) is a demo doing what you want.